# Unable to run grails 2.3.0 M2 through command line

Tags: grails

I just downloaded the milestone edition grails 2.3.0 M2 .zip from the grails [page](http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/milestone/GRAILS/grails-2.3.0.M2.zip) and extracted in the c:\ directory after which it created the folder : C:\grails-2.3.0.M2.

Then I added `C:\grails-2.3.0.M2\bin` to the path system variable. After that when I try to run grails from command line (using `C:\grails-2.3.0.M2\bin>grails`), it gives me the following error:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/grails-2.2.1/lib/org.springs
ource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.3.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

It is interesting to note that the Jar belongs to the grails-2.2.1 installation folder and not the 2.3.0-m2. 
I feel it worth mentioning that I already have grails 2.2.1 in my C drive (C:\grails-2.2.1) and before installing this new version, I was using this version. Also I have removed the old grails bin folder address (C:\grails-2.2.1\bin) from system variables. So anyone can guess what is causing the error?

Comment: Have you got a `%GRAILS_HOME%` variable set?

Comment: Aha!! Got it.Grails_Home was still pointing to the old grails installation directory. So changing it to the new folder wrked!!Kindly mark it as the answer.

Comment: Added as an answer for you to accept :-)  Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you don't have a `%GRAILS_HOME%` variable set pointing to the old folder